# How to expand the div container

Tags: html, vue.js

i want to create swiper with the image show below but the div container is overlapping.

[image]

How should i fix it?

Here is my code

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-8 bg-secondary">
            <div v-swiper:mySwiper="swiperOption">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    <div v-for="(category, index) in categories" :key="index" class="swiper-slide">
                        <categoryBox :category="category" :index="index"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


<div class="swiper-slide" style="margin: 50px 0">
    <div class="bg-white d-inline-flex" style="height: 225px">
        <div class="my-auto pl-5" style="font-size: 2.5rem;  width: 250px">
            {{ category.name }}
        </div>
        <div class="p-3">
            <img :src="category.image" style="border-radius: 50%; height: 200px; width: 200px;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help..

Comment: You should include what you're already researched and tried. This prevents duplicate effort as well as showing that you've actually done research on your own, which is a requirement for this site. If you don't include that stuff, you'll likely get down votes, which would be well deserved.

Comment: Hey there, if you can provide a code snippet it would make things easier.